# PHP redirect/disguise URLs

Tags: php, url

I have a page which receives a parameter and uses it to load it's content.

Let's say the url is `www.myweb.com/category.php?name=shampoo`. What I want is the URL to display `www.myweb.com/shampoo`, and that when some user types `www.myweb.com/shampoo` it actually loads `www.myweb.com/category.php?name=shampoo` but the url keeps displaying `www.myweb.com/shampoo`.

Same thing with, per example, `www.myweb.com/category.php?name=soap` displays as `www.myweb.com/soap`

Is this posible with php? I have made some research but I has not been able to find anything. Thank you very much.

Comment: This is not a question of PHP, you have to deal with such things on level of the protocol, so inside the http server. That apache http server for example offers the rewriting module which allows such things. It is documented, you want to read a bit...

Comment: @arkascha I didn't know this was at apache level and not php. Thank you very much for the data, I will begin reading right now.

Comment: Sure, you are welcome. Reason why this is implemented inside the http server is that php would never get called for such a URL otherwise - why should it? You will find thousands of examples for exactly what you are looking for alone here on SO. This is the documentation of the rewriting module which is where you certainly want to start reading: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html